# GET requests from Chrome browser are blocking the API to receive further requests in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an API "/one" written in Nodejs (version: 12.19.1) which takes 10 seconds to send a response.
request Type: GET

When I hit the API with Jmeter with 10 threads in one second the API is able to process all of them. When I made two requests from Postman the API is able to process them both.

But When I am trying to make two requests from the Chrome Browser. The second request is getting blocked for 10 seconds and sending the response after 20 seconds.

I am not able to figure it out why it is happening only in case of Chrome Browser.

I know it is not blocking the event loop because I am able to access the other API '/two' without any issue.

**Here are the APIs** - The full code is here https://github.com/vnanikalyan/nodeapilimits

*server.js*

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
let cnt = 0;
app.get("/one", async (req, res) => {  
  console.log('Request received! - ', ++cnt);
  const result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/slowrequest")
  const resJson = await result.json()
  res.json(resJson);
})
app.get("/two", (req, res) => {
  res.send("I am unblocked now")
})
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening on port 4000"))
```

*slowserver.js*

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

let cnt = 0;

app.get("/slowrequest", (req, res) => {
  console.log('In slow server - ', ++cnt);
  setTimeout(() => res.json({ message: "sry i was late" }), 10000)
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("listening on port 5000"))
```

Comment: Browsers have their own internal rules on how many requests from one web page they will send to the same host and route when previous requests to that same host/route are still outstanding.  In those cases where there are more outstanding requests than they permit, they will queue the outbound request until one of the previous ones finishes.

Answer (score 0):

delay is for Stalled

[image]

Stalled/Blocking
Time the request spent waiting before it could be sent. This time is inclusive of any time spent in proxy negotiation. Additionally, this time will include when the browser is waiting for an already established connection to become available for re-use, obeying Chrome's maximum six TCP connection per origin rule

if you send request with `Ctrl`+`F5` not `reload this page button` to access to a same domains ,your problem solved